# How to make UIButton vertical silder menu in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

In my application i want to make UIButton slider with scroll view in which when we scroll uiscrollview of buttons then the button will be locate at the center please see these application's first screen sot http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/id422249255?mt=8  how can i do it and what methods i can used for it currently i am used these delegate methods of UIScrollview

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{


}

(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{

}

(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

Add these in header of .m file

```
#define viewWidth 40   //button width
#define viewHeight 30  //button height

#define viewOffsetX 5  //button left ie X
#define viewOffsetY 5  //button right ie Y

#define viewXspace 15  //button from top X space
#define ViewYspace 5   //button from bottom
```

You have images of button add them in array ie arrBtnImages

Now use these method to load button in your scrollView ie scView in viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)loadBtnInSlider
{ 
 int row = 1;
 int col = [arrBtnImages count] / row;

 if ([mut_arrImages count] % col != 0  ) {
    col++;
 }

 int index = 0;
 for (int i=0; i < row  ;  i++)
 {

    CGRect frame;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(viewWidth, viewHeight);
    frame.origin.y = (i * viewHeight) + (i * ViewYspace) + viewOffsetY;

    for (int j= 0; j < col  && index < [mut_arrImages count]; j++) {

        CGRect frame;
        frame.size = CGSizeMake(viewWidth, viewHeight);
        frame.origin.x = (j * viewWidth) + (j * viewXspace) + viewOffsetX;
        frame.origin.y = viewOffsetY;

        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        [btn setTag:j];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelector:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrBtnImages objectAtIndex:j]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        index++;
        [scView addSubview:btn];
        [btn release];
    }
 }
 [scView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(col * (viewWidth+ViewYspace)+viewOffsetY,scView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Use this method in vieDidLoad like this:

```
[self loadBtnInSlider];
```

Now add below selector method for button in .h file and it would be like this

```
-(void)btnSelector:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btnSelected = sender;
   switch(btnSelected.tag) 
   {
      // add case as much u have button
      case 0:
       //first button called
      break;

      case 1:
       //second button called
      break;
      ::
      ::
   }
}
```