# Repeat image in UIScrollView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am new to iPhone,

I want to repeat my PatternImage in ScrollView.

**Logic:** `768bg.gif` is my image and this image i added to `UIImageView` and then Imageview is added to `UIScrollView`, but image is not getting repeated.

Here is my code snippet,

```
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 600);
    UIScrollView *scrollVw = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollVw];
    [scrollVw release];

    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"768bg.gif"]; 
    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image1]; 
    [scrollVw addSubview:self.imageView]; 
    scrollVw.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image1.size.width+100, image1.size.height+100);
```

**Any help will be appriciated.**

Comment: What do you mean by repeat??explain clearly..

Comment: i want to repeat PatternImage.

Comment: yes, i tried this `UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"768bg_with_footer.gif"]; 
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image1]]];` but shows me error sending `void` parameter to `UIImage`

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758704/how-to-make-uibutton-vertical-silder-menu-in-iphone/11759894#11759894 fix col to 3 and row to infinite

Comment: [self.view] will not give an image so i think you should check Tejeshwar Gill's answer.That is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`, from memory.

Comment: How to add this `colorWithPatternImage` to ImageView ?

Comment: `[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:...]]`

Comment: I tried this but getting error `UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"768bg.gif"]; 
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image1]]];`

Comment: No, no. Try this: `ScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"768bg.gif"]];`.

Comment: And also, try using PNGs instead of GIFs. PNG decoding is much faster (they're optimized at framework level), and GIF are paletted image which need color mapping to be displayed on a 32 bit screen, which results in performance drop.

Comment: And to add a little, this method used CoreGraphics to display ONE image many times. It's much better (memory-wise and speed-wise) than the other answers which lead to adding as much UIImageViews as necessary. So why a delete vote for my answer?

Comment: nice ans it's working, i have added background image in the scrollview as you suggested, in scrollview i am adding 30 buttons so now i want scrolling unto 30 button only not more, how to achieve this?

Comment: For that one, start a new question please.

Answer (score 0):

You can consult this link .... What you want to create is an infinite `UIScrollview` right ??
http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Here is some sample code for your understanding ....

```
for(int i=0; i < [Array count]; i++)
{       
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [img setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [img setTag:i];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *ges = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(setImage:)];
    ges.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [img addGestureRecognizer:ges];
    img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
    img.frame = CGRectMake(0, yOffset, 50, 50);
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[Array objectAtIndex:i]];
    [images insertObject:img atIndex:i];    
    ScrollView.layer.cornerRadius = 11;
    [ScrollView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:i]];            
    yOffset += 50;
} 
ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(58,yOffset);
```

Comment: Ya i want infinite scroll but in vertical direction.

Comment: Thats simple just change the contentOffset from the x-axis to the y-axis.... That means keeping the y-axis as the variable and x-axis as constant.... check my edited post have added code..

Comment: When is `img` released in your code? It's already a bad idea to reload the same image many times, and to add a potentially huge number of subviews to a view; but not releasing it at each iteration will lead to a HUGE memory leak here.

Answer (score -2):

1. use a graphic editor to extract all images from your gif (iphone cannot "play" gifs)
2. save resulted images like name1.png, name2.png, name3.png (or whatever extension you need)
3. import the images into your project, then say:

`UIImageView *myImageView = [UIImageView alloc] bla-bla-create-the-imageview];`

```
    [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(bla-bla-whatever)];
            myImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"name1.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"name2.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"name3.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"name4.png"],
                                    nil];
    myImageView.animationDuration = 2.0;//or whatever time interval
    myImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [myImageView startAnimating];
    //add the imageVew to scroll
```

Comment: @iPhone Developer, he said he has added a gif image to a subview and that image wasn't getting repeated... Who is guilty that he is unable to ask a right question? And who, the heck, adds a gif image into an iphone project while he will see only the top layer?

Comment: Well, I am not gonna remove my answer. It reflets exactly the asked question, and I have worked a bit to learn it, and made a bit of effort to post it.

Comment: And take a look to the header: "Repeat image in UIImageView in iPhone", isnt it about repeating images aka animated ones? ... facepalm...

Comment: I did not ask you to do so.But thought it would be good to let you know the exact meaning of the question.But nice efforts!:)

Comment: Folks, you can roll me into minus infinite by downvoting my answer, I will not edit it or remove anyway. As I said, I have answered the asked question, and it was "Repeat image in UIImageView in iPhone" by the time I did it. Stupid questions lead to wrong answers, someone said...